# Android add library via eclipse grayed out

Tags: android, eclipse, android-2.2-froyo

I'm trying to add a library reference to a project and when I go to the Project > Properties > Android window and click Add, the library project is grayed out (see below).  Any idea why this is happening?
The Android sdk is being referenced in the preferences and a build target (version 7) is selected.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Are both projects using JDK 1.6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add/import the project you want to reference as a library into Eclipse and make sure you have it open. The library's API level may not be higher than your project.

If the project is already selected as a reference, you will have to remove it first.

I'm not sure if the JDK version is relevant, but I recall having problems with referenced libraries under version 1.6.

Comment: Your comment helped, however, to resolve this, I needed to import the library as a separate project, set the build type to library and then select the "referenced project" from my main project using the Project Selection.  
This seems a bit overly complex, I thought there'd be an easier way to do this.  
Am I missing something or is this how the reference needs to be added?

Comment: No, you've done it correctly. I had forgotten to mention that the project that you wish to reference as a library must have "is library" enabled in the project's Android settings.